Outcome Level vs. Treatment Level vs. Fixed-Effects Level in Difference-in-Differences
I am a bit confused about what controls should I include in my event-study (Callaway and Santanna 2021) specifications.
One of my models tries to understand the impact of the opening of a public facility (treatment is municipal-level) on also municipal-level outcomes. I am worried about time-varying cofounders like municipal GDP, municipal population growth, etc., that may affect the outcome in treated cities. Would municipality-year fixed effects account for those? Or should I actually insert these covariates in the model?
The other model is similar, but tries to assess the impact of the public facilities roll-out (municipal) on individual-level outcomes (such as if the person is employed, etc). Since the outcome is at a more granular level than the treatment, are factors like municipal GDP growth a problem? Municipality-year fixed effects are necessary?
Thanks in advance.

Welcome. Are you working with a municipal-year panel?

Hello. The first model is municipal-level, and second individual-level. Both receive treatment at municipal-level in different years.


One of my models tries to understand the impact of the opening of a public facility (treatment is municipal-level) on also municipal-level outcomes. I am worried about time-varying cofounders like municipal GDP, municipal population growth, etc., that may affect the outcome in treated cities. Would municipality-year fixed effects account for those?

The municipal-year fixed effects do more than just adjust for factors that vary across municipalities and years; they may completely absorb any variation in your municipal-year policy variables. If your data is ‘aggregated up’ to the municipal level, the fixed effects essentially account for all the variation in both the municipalities and the years, leaving little to no variation for estimating other parameters. In other words, by estimating a separate fixed effect for each municipal-year combination, you exhaust all your degrees of freedom, making it impossible to estimate the effect of other variables in the model.

Or should I actually insert these covariates in the model?

I would.
Including covariates is important if they affect the outcome and are not themselves outcomes of the treatment. Adjusting for these factors helps control for confounding variables that could bias your estimates. In practice, the municipal level covariates should show variation over time (i.e., across municipal-years).

The other model is similar, but tries to assess the impact of the public facilities roll-out (municipal) on individual-level outcomes (such as if the person is employed, etc). Since the outcome is at a more granular level than the treatment, are factors like municipal GDP growth a problem?

Absolutely not.
Since your treatment is at the municipal level, municipal-level covariates matter with respect to the identification of your treatment effect. Including variables like municipal GDP or population is important in this context and will help improve the robustness of your analysis.

Municipality-year fixed effects are necessary?

While municipal-year fixed effects can be included with individual-level data, it’s not recommended when the treatment is at the municipal level. These fixed effects would absorb your municipal-year policy variables, such as the opening of public institutions. In other words, municipal-year effects is a form of ‘over-controlling’ when estimating the impact of municipal-year policy changes.
Instead, consider estimating county-year fixed effects. Municipalities typically operate within county boundaries, and accounting for county-level variation can capture important differences in local regulations. This is just a suggestion.

Thank you! In the country I’m studying, municipalities are equivalent to cities and fall within states, with no intermediate administrative level. From your response, I understand that it would be beneficial to include state-year fixed effects in the individual-level outcome model, in addition to time-varying municipal variables like GDP per capita and population. Would it also make sense (econometrically) to include non-varying individual covariates such as race and gender?
